# How can I see where I have used myopenid as login?

Tags: discussion, support, login, openid

Some time ago I was using myopenid.com on SO sites. Traveling around, I have seen it is still registered on one of sites or settings (within a title something `alt openid` or `alt login` etc.). Unfortunately I lost it suddenly. I want to remove it because I do not use it anymore. Where can I find it, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) on Stack Overflow, go to the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab and click the "My Logins" section:

> [image: my logins location]

Comment: There is only Stack Exchange account there, currently I am using.

Comment: Then you must have removed the MyOpenId one at some point. (given they've stopped operations a couple of years ago... not surprising).

Comment: I have seen it in some records this morning, but I did not have a chance to remove it. I even can not find that page (with `alt sth.`).

Comment: From what I can see against your account, a myopenid credential was removed from it about 3 years ago.

Comment: I have found it on https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/350xxx, thanks for spending me some time.